# Forcing change event on grid

Tags: extjs, extjs3

We have a gridpanel in ExtJs 3.2,with a text field as an editor on one of the columns:

```
var psp_config= {
store:ProjectSponsorView.s_store,
.....
tbar: new Ext.Toolbar({     
... 
}),
......
columns: [
....
{header: '% Contribution', 
  renderer:  Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('000.00'),
  editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
         listeners: {
            'change' : function (field, newValue, oldValue) {
                ........
            }
         }
      })

}
```

We have a situation wherein the change event of teh editor does not get fired  if the user submits the form, while the focus is still within the editor/column.
This causes the stale data to be submitted for that particular column.
How do we forcibly have the gridpanel/column/editor to register/accept the changed value in such a case?

Comment: Why not manually fire the event using `fireEvent( 'change', ... )`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you use EditorGridPanel? If so, maybe attach to its afteredit event:

[image]

Config would look something like this:

```
......
columns: [
....
  {
    header: '% Contribution', 
    renderer:  Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('000.00'),
    editor: new Ext.form.TextField({})
  }
],
listeners: {
  afteredit: function(e) {
    //handle changes here
  }
}
```